# how do i update mulitple rows with dynamic data?

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite to update mulipte rows, but it does not work.

`item` table to keep the item data

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      10
2      10
3      10
```

`user_basket` table to keep users' basket data

```
user_ID item_ID  Bask_Qty 
-        -       - 
1        1       5
1        2       1
2        1       1
```

I used command like:

```
UPDATE item 
SET Qty = 
(SELECT Qty-Bask_Qty FROM user_basket 
INNER JOIN item ON item.item_ID = user_basket.item_ID) 
WHERE item_ID IN (SELECT item_ID FROM user_basket WHERE user_ID = 1);
```

After the command, I should expect `item` table be like that:

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      5
2      9
3      10
```

but instead, I got:

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      5
2      5
3      10
```

apparently, it used the same value to update all the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE item AS i
SET Qty = i.Qty - COALESCE(
  (SELECT SUM(b.Bask_Qty) FROM user_basket b WHERE b.user_ID = 1 AND b.item_ID = i.item_ID), 
  0
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a5c5e62f75e692c0b83881605700b0b).

Or, with a `WHERE` clause to avoid unnecessary updates:

```
UPDATE item AS i
SET Qty = i.Qty - (SELECT SUM(b.Bask_Qty) FROM user_basket b WHERE b.user_ID = 1 AND b.item_ID = i.item_ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_basket b WHERE b.user_ID = 1 AND b.item_ID = i.item_ID)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6421146e7b8128fb90287f73654445b9).

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax:

```
UPDATE item AS i
SET Qty = i.Qty - b.Bask_Qty 
FROM (SELECT item_ID, SUM(Bask_Qty) Bask_Qty FROM user_basket WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY item_ID) AS b
WHERE b.item_id = i.item_id
```

In all of the above queries I used `SUM(Bask_Qty)` to return the quantity of each item from the table `user_basket`, just in case there are more than 1 rows for each item.
If you are sure that there may be only 1 row for each item then replace it with just `Bask_Qty`.